# How to retry multiple steps in step Function?

Tags: aws-step-functions

I have a usecase where I have a chain of steps which repeats for another set as well. As per different usecases, I want to retry my step in chain based on some conditions. I tried using a choice state, which is checking the value of a flag, but since I have 2 different steps using the same function to add a step to my emr cluster, I need 2 different flags to differentiate between them. I cannot use array here because my steps are executed in a chain and the index will vary for the other step. Is there a way i could add a choice state with a variable in Condition.booleanEquals. Or is there any workaround for retrying multiple steps in step function?